# Plot upside down geom_col() plot with ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.
I want to plot on the one y-axis the y-values of the diamond dataset
and on the negative y-axis, the z-values of the diamond dataset.

When I try this, I get very absurd values since the max of y and z are far smaller.

```r
library(ggplot2)
  
ggplot(data = diamonds) + 
  geom_col(aes(x = x,y = y), color="#edae49") + 
  geom_col(aes(x = x,y = -z), color="#66a182") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

```r
max(diamonds$y)
#> [1] 58.9
max(diamonds$z)
#> [1] 31.8
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

any idea what I am doing so wrong? 
**I want to see bars from min to max in each position.**

Comment: The bars are stacked, so you are getting the sum of the values at each point in x. Try `position = "identity"`

Comment: Thank you! I have another example to post where it does not work for me. I'll do it asap. Please post it in the answer to upvote it. Thank you again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(ggplot2)
  
ggplot(data = diamonds) + 
  geom_col(aes(x = x, y = y), color="#edae49", position = 'identity') + 
  geom_col(aes(x = x, y = -z), color="#66a182", position = 'identity') +
  theme_bw()
```

[image: Positive/Negative geom_col]